# Can't access document on new open window JS

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am trying to get some data from a webpage and pass it to new window and print it from there. Here is my code:

```
var print_btn;
let win;

document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML +"<button class=\"printbuton\">Print Button</button>";

print_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('printbuton')[0];

print_btn.onclick = function() {
    
    console.log("check 1");
    
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=384,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    console.log("check 2");
    WinPrint.document.write('Print this');
    console.log("check 3");
    WinPrint.document.write('Print that');
    WinPrint.document.write('and this');
    
    console.log("button pushed");
}
```

When I try this it opens the new window, but it stays empty and in console it logs only "check 1" and "check 2".
I tested that if i console.log(WinPrint) it shows in console, but if I do console.log(WinPrint.document) it doesn't show anything and the script stops there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work due to a [(XSS [Cross Site Scripting])](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) Error. Firefox is preventing you from altering the content of a different domain.

Since you're opening a new window, you now have a different domain name (about:blank) than the one you started on.

There's a few ways to go about this, what comes quickly to mind would be to use the [`window.create` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create) and use query params to pass the data to the new window:

```
function onCreated(windowInfo) {
  console.log('SUCCESS');
}

function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

print_btn.addEventListener('click', event => {

  var popupURL = browser.extension.getURL("popup/popup.html?line=blahblah&line2=loremipsum");

  var creating = browser.windows.create({
    url: popupURL,
    type: "popup",
    height: 200,
    width: 200
  });
  creating.then(onCreated, onError);

});
```

Or you could do something more elaborate by opening using `windows.create`, then using [`runtime.sendmessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage) to pass messages back to the background script and then to the new window.

OR you could probably inject a popup into the page itself and do something similiar.